# Powering off multiple monitors programmatically

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, winapi, multiple-monitors

I'm looking for a way to programmatically power off multiple monitors.

Note: This doesn't mean power off ALL monitors.

The languages I'm currently able to compile in with my current enviorment is python/C/C++. I am aware of the easy C++ way of.

```
SendMessage(GetConsoleWindow(), WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, 2);
```

However this powers off all the monitors the system has on, which isn't the result I'm after.

Let's say I have a Window with the name "Application Window", now I want to power off all of the monitors that does not have this app window open.

Note: Ideally it'd be implemented with python, however not needed.

Edit:
Found this, however I'm unable to recreate it and have the desired functionality.

[Cpp how to turn off specific monitor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32847726/cpp-how-to-turn-off-specific-monitor)

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if you're not able to turn off individual monitors except by disabling the monitor. The power management software in Windows wouldn't need to do that. Either all monitors are in power saving mode (turned off) or they're all not.

Comment: @RossRidge If i were to disable the monitor, would it the applications opened on that monitor be moved over to another monitor or would they persist on that monitor/pixel location?

Comment: If you a disable a monitor Windows will move any windows on that monitor to another enabled monitor.

Comment: @RossRidge Mhm you think something like making the display(s) display a pure black screen saver might do the trick?

Comment: It looks like the answer you linked suggesting using `SetVCPFeature` should do the trick, but I can't get it to work either. GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR just returns NULL handles for me.

Answer (score -2):

Using [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ctypes.html) you can access the winapi functions you mentioned:

```
import ctypes

WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112
SC_MONITORPOWER = 0xF170

window = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleWindow()

ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageA(window, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, 2);
```

The msdn documentation:

- [SendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [GetConsoleWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683175(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [WM_SYSCOMMAND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360(v=vs.85).aspx)

You should use [GetDesktopWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633504(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
window = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetDesktopWindow()
```

Comment: Okay, but how do you turn off *specific* monitors?

Comment: He said it is as easy as of ... I just replicated it in python

Comment: Anyway the using the winapi all the monitors will be turned off. I see no option to turn on monitors separately.

Comment: Yeah this is nice, but not exactly what I'm looking for, this is the same as the C++ solution which isn't what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @sza Please read the question again